# Por que não consigo fazer a leitura desse character?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Sou novo na programação; a pergunta da questão é essa:

> Tendo como dados de entrada o nome, a altura e o sexo (M ou F) de uma
>   pessoa, calcule e mostre seu peso ideal, utilizando as seguintes
>   fórmulas:
>
> • para sexo masculino: peso ideal = (72.7 * altura) – 58
>
> • para sexo feminino: peso ideal = (62.1 * altura) – 44.7

No entanto, no código, ele não faz a leitura do dado Masculino e Feminino.

Queria saber porque não consigo fazer a leitura?

O **scanf** é a melhor maneira para fazer leituras de caracteres?

Muito obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    unsigned char nome[50],gen;
    float alt,resultado;


    printf("Qual o seu nome?\n");
    scanf("%s",&nome);

    printf("Qual o seu genero [M] ou [F] para feminino?\n");
    scanf("%c",&gen);

    printf("Qual a sua altura?\n");
    scanf("%f",&alt);

    if (gen == 'M') { 
        resultado == (72.7 * alt) - 58;
        printf("O seu peso ideal é: %.1f",resultado);
    } else if (gen == 'F') {
        resultado == (62.1 * alt) - 44.7;
        printf("O seu peso ideal é: %.1f",resultado);
    } else {
        printf("\n letra inválida, informe  M ou F\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) automaticamente consome espaços em branco, antes da conversão, provenientes do fluxo de entrada padrão *stdin* quando o especificador de conversão **não é** um dos seguintes: `%c`, `%n` e `%[]`.

Isso significa que, após

```
scanf("%s", nome); // remova '&', esse é o jeito correto de ler uma string com scanf
```

existe um caractere de quebra de linha `\n` no fluxo de entrada, esperando para ser consumido. Como seu próximo comando é

```
scanf("%c", &gen);
```

a função `scanf` vai armazenar o caractere de quebra de linha em `gen`.

---

Para resolver, utilize um espaço em branco antes do especificador de conversão `%c`

```
scanf(" %c", &gen);
```

O espaço em branco diz à função `scanf` para pular o primeiro espaço em branco, e o primeiro caractere que não seja um espaço em branco será lido com o especificador de conversão `%c`.

Adicionalmente, ambas as atribuições à `resultado` estão erradas. O operador de atribuição é somente o caractere `=`

```
resultado = (72.7 * alt) - 58;
...
resultado = (62.1 * alt) - 44.7;
```