# Problema para entrar no Switch

Tags: c, funções, switch

Boa tarde, ao executar o programa abaixo, após digitar a terceira nota, o programa se encerra sem digitar a letra necessária para entrar no switch. Testei com o "i" recebendo numero inteiro e o programa funcionou.

Obrigado.

```
float media_aritmetica(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3);

float media_ponderada(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3);

int main(){

    float nota1, nota2, nota3;
    float m;
    char i;

    printf("Digite o valor da primeira nota:");
    scanf("%f", &nota1);
    printf("Digite o valor da segunda nota:");
    scanf("%f", &nota2);
    printf("Digite o valor da terceira nota:");
    scanf("%f", &nota3);

    printf("Escolha uma das opcoes abaixo:\n");
    printf("A| Media Aritmetica\n");
    printf("B| Media Ponderada\n");
    scanf("%c", &i);

    switch(i){

        case 'A':
            m = media_aritmetica(nota1,nota2,nota3);
            printf("A media aritmetica eh: %.2f", m);
            break;

        case 'B':
            m = media_ponderada(nota1,nota2,nota3);
            printf("A media ponderada eh : %.2f", m);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Letra Invalida!");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

float media_aritmetica(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3){
    float media;
    media = (nota1+nota2+nota3)/3;
    return media;
}

float media_ponderada(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3){
    float media;
    media= ((5*nota1)+(3*nota2)+(2*nota3))/5+3+2;
    return media;
}
```

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250506/por-que-n%C3%A3o-consigo-fazer-a-leitura-desse-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você dá o enter na terceira nota, a variável i recebe o valor do enter (\n) que está no buffer do teclado.

Você pode solucionar de 3 formas:

A primeira é colocar um espaço antes do %c, pois ele só leria depois do espaço

```
    scanf(" %c", &i);
```

Outra solução seria mudar o scanf("%c", &i); para um getch()

```
    i = getch();
```

Outra seria colocar 2 scanf, um para receber o valor do enter e outro para receber o valor do caractere

```
    scanf("%c", &i);
    scanf("%c", &i);
```